# JavaScript where in the code a value was updated

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to find out where a variable was updated from in the code, 
example:

```
var value = 'foo';
//Huge mass of code here
value = 'oof' //How can I find out what line this was run?
//Some more code
```

I have tried to ctr + f and search for 'value = ' but the code updates it some other way, break points wont work as I don't know the point where the code is run.

Comment: It is probably being updated in a function call, possibly.

Comment: If the code updates it some way _other_ than `value =`, why is it part of your example?